# How to find average difference in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table employee storing the details of the employee.

```
ssn : social security number of the employee
address : storing the address of the employee
```

Looking at the address field in the employee table, you would notice that all the employees reside in "Fondren, Houston, TX". Consider the integer in the address field as house number. Consider the distance between the two houses as the difference in the house numbers, so the distance between house number 2 and 38 is 36 units. Write a query to determine the average distance between the house of the employee with `ssn = '123456789'` and the other employees' houses. Print the answer to two decimal places. Make sure that the answer is formatted with a comma like x,xxx.xx .

Can someone please help me solving this problem?

I do not want to use a SQL function.

The query I have made is:

```
SELECT 
    avg(
    abs(CAST(address AS UNSIGNED) - 
    SELECT CAST(address AS UNSIGNED) from test.test where ssn = 1234)
    ) as average from test.test;
```

Comment: This sounds like homework.  You should at least make this a complete question by including sample data.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't want to include the distance from the employee's house to their own house, you need to compute the average excluding that. One way to do that is by `CROSS JOIN`ing a table of the numbers of employee houses *not* including the employee of interest, and a table of the number of the employee of interest's house. You can then compute the `SUM` of the absolute differences and divide that by the row count to get the average. You can then use `FORMAT` to get the output in the desired format:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(ABS(oth - emp)) / COUNT(oth), 2) AS average
FROM (
      SELECT CAST(address AS SIGNED) AS oth
      FROM test
      WHERE ssn != '123456789'
     ) t
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT CAST(address AS SIGNED) AS emp
      FROM test
      WHERE ssn = '123456789'
     ) t2
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/008759/4)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT format (avg(abs(substring_index(address, ' ', 1)-(SELECT 
    substring_index(address, ' ', 1)
    FROM employee
    WHERE ssn = '123456789'
))), 2)
FROM employee
WHERE ssn != '123456789';
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.